# Where do I ask a math related computer question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a math-oriented computer programming question that I'd like to ask and I'm not sure if it belongs on Stack Overflow or Math. The problem is that I can really only explain it in the context of a computer program.

Should I ask it on Stack Overflow or do my best to ask it on Math?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only math enthusiasts who are also professional programmers could answer it, it should probably go on SO.

If, contrariwise, only programmers who are also professional mathematicians could answer it, it should probably go on Math.

If it requires a serious expert in both fields, ask it on either site, but be prepared for a certain difficulty in getting answers.

Comment: There is also [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) site which *may* be better place for complex problems related to algorithms (i.e. optimal algorithm for solution rather than mere existence of one)

Answer (score 2):

If its a programming question you may ask it on SO.

You may ask the question on SO, explaining your math aspect too.